# Flume Agent Unknown Error

Tags: hadoop, hbase, flume

Im getting bellow error on my flume agent where I use *AsyncHbaseEventSerializer*.
I doubt is this because of my schema. I have two column families.

```
MyAgent.sinks.MySink.columnFamily=family1,family2
```

When I specify both column families coma separated Im getting error as table/column family not found.

```
MyAgent.sinks.MySink.columnFamily=family1 family2
```

If I specify both column families separated by space then I think only first column family considered.

This is the error. Can anyone help me?

```
Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: Could not write events to Hbase. Transaction failed, and rolled back.
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink.process(AsyncHBaseSink.java:317)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Update:

```
myAgent.sources = TwitterSource InstagramSource FacebookSource
myAgent.channels = TwitterChannel InstagramChannelMedia InstagramChannelMediaComment FacebookChannelPage FacebookChannelPost FacebookChannelComment
myAgent.sinks = TwitterSink InstagramSinkMedia InstagramSinkMediaComment FacebookSinkPage FacebookSinkPost FacebookSinkComment

myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.type = com.my.socialanalytics.core.twitter.TwitterSource
myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.channels = TwitterChannel
myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.consumerKey = <>
myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.consumerSecret = <>
myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.accessToken = <>
myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.accessTokenSecret = <>
myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.crawlingFrequency = 300000
myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.mongoHost =10.3.0.38
myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.mongoPort =27017
myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.mongoDBName =mySocialAnalytics
myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.mongoCollectionCampaigns =Campaigns
myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.mongoUsername =admin
myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.mongoPassword =qburst
myAgent.sources.TwitterSource.mongoAuthDB =admin

myAgent.sinks.TwitterSink.type=org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink
myAgent.sinks.TwitterSink.channel=TwitterChannel
myAgent.sinks.TwitterSink.table=Tweets
myAgent.sinks.TwitterSink.columnFamily=campaign tweet
myAgent.sinks.TwitterSink.serializer=com.my.socialanalytics.core.twitter.TwitterSerializer
myAgent.sinks.TwitterSink.serializer.columns=tweet:contributors tweet:createdAt tweet:inReplyToUserID tweet:text tweet:inReplyToStatusID tweet:source tweet:lang tweet:geo tweet:favorited tweet:withheldCopyright campaign:stateCode tweet:truncated tweet:entities tweet:inReplyToScreenName tweet:withheldInCountries campaign:campaignID tweet:favoriteCount tweet:id tweet:user tweet:retweetedStatus campaign:countryCode tweet:possiblySensitive tweet:currentUserRetweet tweet:retweetCount tweet:withheldScope tweet:retweeted tweet:coordinates tweet:filterLevel tweet:quotedStatusID campaign:sentiment tweet:place
myAgent.sinks.TwitterSink.batchSize = 50

myAgent.channels.TwitterChannel.type = memory
myAgent.channels.TwitterChannel.capacity = 10000000
myAgent.channels.TwitterChannel.transactionCapacity = 100000

myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.type = com.my.socialanalytics.core.instagram.InstagramSource
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.channels = InstagramChannelMedia InstagramChannelMediaComment
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.clientID = <>
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.clientSecret = <>
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.accessToken = <>
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.crawlingFrequency = 3600000
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.mongoHost =10.3.0.38
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.mongoPort =27017
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.mongoDBName =mySocialAnalytics
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.mongoCollectionCampaigns =Campaigns
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.mongoUsername =admin
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.mongoPassword =qburst
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.mongoAuthDB =admin
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.selector.type = multiplexing
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.selector.header = feedType
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.selector.mapping.feedTypeMedia = InstagramChannelMedia
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.selector.mapping.feedTypeComment = InstagramChannelMediaComment
myAgent.sources.InstagramSource.selector.default = InstagramChannelMedia

myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMedia.type=org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink
myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMedia.channel=InstagramChannelMedia
myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMedia.table=InstagramMedia
myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMedia.columnFamily=campaign media
myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMedia.serializer=com.my.socialanalytics.core.instagram.InstagramMediaSerializer
myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMedia.serializer.columns=media:createdTime campaign:campaignID media:link media:videos media:type media:caption campaign:countryCode media:filter media:likes media:attribution media:comments media:user campaign:updatedAt media:tags campaign:stateCode media:images campaign:sentiment media:location media:id
myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMedia.batchSize = 50

myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMediaComment.type=org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink
myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMediaComment.channel=InstagramChannelMediaComment
myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMediaComment.table=InstagramComments
myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMediaComment.columnFamily=campaign comment
myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMediaComment.serializer=com.my.socialanalytics.core.instagram.InstagramMediaCommentSerializer
myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMediaComment.serializer.columns=comment:mediaId comment:id campaign:campaignID comment:createdTime campaign:updatedAt comment:from comment:text campaign:sentiment
myAgent.sinks.InstagramSinkMediaComment.batchSize = 50

myAgent.channels.InstagramChannelMedia.type = memory
myAgent.channels.InstagramChannelMedia.capacity = 10000000
myAgent.channels.InstagramChannelMedia.transactionCapacity = 100000

myAgent.channels.InstagramChannelMediaComment.type = memory
myAgent.channels.InstagramChannelMediaComment.capacity = 10000000
myAgent.channels.InstagramChannelMediaComment.transactionCapacity = 100000

myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.type = com.my.socialanalytics.core.facebook.FacebookSource
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.channels = FacebookChannelPage FacebookChannelPost FacebookChannelComment
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.accessToken = <>
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.crawlingFrequency = 3600000
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.mongoHost =10.3.0.38
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.mongoPort =27017
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.mongoDBName =mySocialAnalytics
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.mongoCollectionCampaigns =Campaigns
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.mongoUsername =admin
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.mongoPassword =qburst
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.mongoAuthDB =admin
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.selector.type = multiplexing
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.selector.header = feedType
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.selector.mapping.feedTypePage = FacebookChannelPage
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.selector.mapping.feedTypePost = FacebookChannelPost
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.selector.mapping.feedTypeComment = FacebookChannelComment
myAgent.sources.FacebookSource.selector.default = FacebookChannelPage

myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPage.type=org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPage.channel=FacebookChannelPage
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPage.table=FacebookPages
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPage.columnFamily=campaign page
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPage.serializer=com.my.socialanalytics.core.facebook.FacebookPageSerializer
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPage.serializer.columns=page:talkingAboutCount campaign:campaignID page:name page:wereHereCount page:fanCount page:id page:checkins campaign:day
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPage.batchSize = 50

myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPost.type=org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPost.channel=FacebookChannelPost
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPost.table=FacebookPosts
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPost.columnFamily=post campaign
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPost.serializer=com.my.socialanalytics.core.facebook.FacebookPostSerializer
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPost.serializer.columns=post:link campaign:campaignID post:place post:sharesCount post:name post:from campaign:updatedAt post:caption post:id post:likesCount post:createdTime post:message campaign:sentiment
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkPost.batchSize = 50

myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkComment.type=org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkComment.channel=FacebookChannelComment
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkComment.table=FacebookComments
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkComment.columnFamily=campaign comment
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkComment.serializer=com.my.socialanalytics.core.facebook.FacebookCommentSerializer
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkComment.serializer.columns=comment:message comment:id campaign:campaignID comment:commentCount comment:parent comment:createdTime campaign:updatedAt comment:from comment:postID campaign:sentiment
myAgent.sinks.FacebookSinkComment.batchSize = 50

myAgent.channels.FacebookChannelPage.type = memory
myAgent.channels.FacebookChannelPage.capacity = 10000000
myAgent.channels.FacebookChannelPage.transactionCapacity = 100000

myAgent.channels.FacebookChannelPost.type = memory
myAgent.channels.FacebookChannelPost.capacity = 10000000
myAgent.channels.FacebookChannelPost.transactionCapacity = 100000

myAgent.channels.FacebookChannelComment.type = memory
myAgent.channels.FacebookChannelComment.capacity = 10000000
myAgent.channels.FacebookChannelComment.transactionCapacity = 100000
```

Initially Im not getting any error but after couple of hours getting such error. Im running some spark jobs to update particular field in same table. Im no sure if its the reason. My flume frequently updating same records. Is that the reason for this error?

Update 2:
If im mentioning both column families im getting error as below.

```
   Oct 14, 4:21:11.040 PM   ERROR   org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor  
    Unable to start SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@4c74990e counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } } - Exception follows.
    org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Could not start sink. Table or column family does not exist in Hbase.
        at 

org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink.initHBaseClient(AsyncHBaseSink.java:489)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink.start(AsyncHBaseSink.java:441)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.start(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:46)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.start(SinkRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If i mention only one column family Im getting error

```
Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: Could not write events to Hbase. Transaction failed, and rolled back.
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink.process(AsyncHBaseSink.java:317)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Hi Vaisakh, Can you post whole flume sink configuration file?.

Comment: @Vijay_Shinde Thanks for the response. Updated question with config

Comment: It seems your configuration is correct. But still need more about exception. Can you please update whole stack trace of your exception?

Comment: @Vijay_Shinde Updated question. Cant we specify two column families for a sync?

Comment: I tried with one column family & its working. Can you firstly try with single column family.

Comment: I tried with one column family and it works. But after couple of hours getting that last error. May be when my flume update already existing row there might be some schema mismatch. I mean actually i have two column families but we mentioned only one na? So that my doubt if its the reason or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125694/discussion-between-vaisakh-and-vijay-shinde).